# How to keep a service from closing?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, ram, stock-android, gps-tracking, services

I am using the latest stock ROM for my phone (SGS3, Vodafone variant, although rooted) and I have installed a [GPS live tracking program](http://www.greenalp.com/RealTimeTracker/) that stays on the taskbar as a service all the time (and that's the way I want it to).

When I load up some RAM-hungry games that I've installed, sometimes that service dies (along with other processes that I don't care about) because Android tries to free up memory automatically (I have no task killer installed).

Is there a way to make that service having higher priority, so it won't get scooped along the other things that Android's garbage collector trashes when I open my favorite enormous apps?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I've found and seems to be working with more than one services, is to make sure that I leave open in the task manager the applications I do not want to be closed down.

This isn't a bulletproof approach, but it works for hours or even days (at least in my case) and it's much faster than manually changing OOM priority (only to find out that OOM changes back after a while by the system itself).

Ideal solution would be an application that monitors OOM of services specified by the user and making sure it's kept at certain levels, but I haven't found any that can do that until now.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Auto Memory Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lim.android.automemman&hl=en) and set your minfree values on the secondary server lower so it has lower chances killing off services. You can also increase the OOM priority of the service to 0 (lower values means less chance of being killed), also part of app.

Comment: From the [FAQ](http://madsquirrelapps.com/faq/): **I’ve set a app’s priority to “keep-alive” but it changes back after a while.  What’s happening??**
Unfortunately this is outside of my control.  I have the ability to change the priorities but unfortunately the kernel is still managing the priorities and will set the priorities to what it deems suitable.  As we were never meant to change priorities manually I think there may be no provision to stick to manually adjusted priorities.

Comment: Not all apps are perfect and android has limititations. But still there is no other app I know of that can efficiently adjust the memory killer like this one.

Comment: I know at least one more that has this ability (with the same limitation). It's called [AutoKiller Memory Optimizer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rs.autokiller). Unfortunately that doesn't give a solution to my problem. I'll wait a bit longer in case someone knows something that you and I don't, before accepting your answer. For now, as you can see, I've just voted it up.